# CreateProcess function instead of system

Tags: c++, winapi, system, createprocess

I have created a code which using windows forms application in order to construct a gui. I am using system command in my code in order to call an external .exe. However this approach creates a command line terminal.  I found that I can replace system with CreateProcess function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908775.aspx). How should I use this function? What parameters should I specify in order to run? My code now is:

```
 string run_template = "a.exe -i " + s1 + " -r 10 -f image2  filename%03d.jpg";
 system(run_template.c_str());
```

EDIT:

```
 #include <tchar.h>

 string workPath = "";
 string args = "-i " + s1 + " -r 10 -f image2  vid/frames/filename%03d.jpg";

 HINSTANCE hRet = ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("a.exe"), _T(args.c_str()), _T(workPath.c_str()), SW_HIDE);
 DWORD errNum = GetLastError();
```

I got the following error:

```
1>c\projects\first_api\first_api\Form1.h(229): error  C2065: 'Largs' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\projects\first_api\first_api\Form1.h(229): error C2228: left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type'' 
1>c:\projects\first_api\first_api\Form1.h(229): error C2065: 'LworkPath' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\projects\first_api\first_api\Form1.h(229): error C2228: left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union
```

EDIT2:

```
string run_template = "a.exe -i " + s1 + " -r 1 -f image2 /filename%03d.jpg";
//system(run_template.c_str());

STARTUPINFOA si = {sizeof(STARTUPINFOA), 0};
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};

if (CreateProcessA(NULL, const_cast<char*>(run_template.c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))   {
     CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
     CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

The command prompt still exists when using the above code.

Comment: The link you provide is to the old Windows Mobile 6.5 version. While it should be the same as for the full Windows version you might want to [use a link for the proper version first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That link, by the way, contains a [link to a complete example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Are you asking about `CreateProcess` or about compilation errors you get from using `ShellExecute`? Those two are different things! You can keep this question (after trying to use `CreateProcess` and adding that attempt), and ask a new question about using `ShellExecute`.

Comment: Yea, I ve changed question due to Aravind at Vembu answer. Basically I want to replace system in order to hide the command line.

Comment: Then update the *complete* question, including the title, to reflect the new question. Or post a new questions.

Comment: `CreateProcess` is well documented. Why can't you simply read the documentation and call it. It does't look like you have tried to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string run_template = "a.exe -i " + s1 + " -r 10 -f image2  filename%03d.jpg";

STARTUPINFOA si = {sizeof(STARTUPINFOA), 0};
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};

vector<char> cmdline(run_template.begin(), run_template.end());
if (CreateProcessA(NULL, &cmdline[0], NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: error C2664: 'CreateProcessA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char *' to 'LPSTR'

Comment: The second parameter is not declared as `const` but the pointer returned by `c_str()` is. You will have to cast it away.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to understand but I am getting into a bigger mess here. I have tried your solution now I am getting  cannot convert parameter 9 from 'STARTUPINFO *' to 'LPSTARTUPINFOA'

Comment: You need to change the STARTUPINFO structure to a STARTUPINFOA structure as the example is using CreateProcessA() rather than CreateProcess() (which is a macro that determines which version to call based on your UNICODE settings). The example can't use STARTUPINFO and CreateProcess() as you'd expect it to because it's using a std::string which is not 'UNICODE/non UNICODE' aware and so is ALWAYS char * based rather than conditionally being a wchar_t * based when UNICODE is enabled...

Comment: I have changed STARTUPINFO to STARTUPINFOA and it works. However the commnand line still appears.

Comment: @RemyLebeau no, don't cast it away. The string must be writable. Copy it to a writable buffer and pass the writable buffer.

Comment: @RaymondChen: The pointer returned by `c_str()` is already pointing at writable memory in most STL implementations, it is just being returned as a `const` pointer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The writability of `c_str()` is not guaranteed by spec. (Copy on write was legal until recently, as I recall.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: maybe, but the issue is still moot, since the code is calling `CreateProcessA()`, which does not write to the parameter, only `CreateProcessW()` does.

Comment: Yeah, but if you do `vector<char> buf(run_template.begin(), run_template.end());` and use `&buf[0]` in place of the `const_cast` expression, the code won't be relying on those esoteric implementation details. As an added bonus, now the code won't be subtly broken when someone decides to use the unicode api (and of course change char to WCHAR).

Answer (score -5):

You can use the ShellExecute function instead, which is very easy to understand.

Example:

```
string workPath = "D:\\MyWorkPath\";
string args = "-i " + s1 + " -r 10 -f image2  filename%03d.jpg

LPCTSTR lArgs = args.c_str();
LPCTSTR lPath = workPath.c_str();
HINSTANCE hRet = ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("a.exe"), lArgs, lPath, SW_HIDE);
```

The final argument in ShellExecute function hides the console window.

Note: Be sure the application you are running (a.exe) is not blocking, i.e., doesn't wait for getting input from you. Or simply, you are not using any cin/scanf's in a.exe application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting '_T': identifier not found.

Comment: _T is a macro to make a strings "character set neutral". To fix this issue, include "tchar.h" file.

Comment: Yes you are right I ve already check it. I have got other problems with macro L.

Comment: The `_T` macro can only be used for string literals, not variables.

Comment: Hm how can I do that using variable?

Comment: Oops! My bad. You can use the string variable directly with .c_str().

Comment: HINSTANCE hRet = ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("a.exe"), args.c_str(), workPath.c_str(), SW_HIDE);

Comment: `ShellExecute` is the wrong function when passing an executable function. Use `CreateProcess`. Why get `ShellExecute` to call `CreateProcess` when you can call it directly? And don't recommend `ShellExecute` which is deprecated and cannot report errors properly. Use `ShellExecuteEx`. Do not call `GetLastError` unconditionally. It is particularly egregious here since `ShellExecute` doesn't report errors that way.

Comment: error C2664: 'ShellExecuteW' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'

Comment: @FereRes What does that comment mean?

Comment: Yea you are right, I tried to use HINSTANCE hRet = ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("a.exe"), args.c_str(), workPath.c_str(), SW_HIDE);

Comment: Hmmmmmmm....... 
You can assign that value into a LPCTSTR type variable and use it. Edited the answer above.

Comment: @AravindatVembu No, your edit won't convert from ANSI encoded text to UTF-16 encoded text. `SW_HIDE` might hide the window. But it's the wrong way to suppress a console window. `CreateProcess` with `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` is the right way.